# JPA Many To One relationship Update aggregated column in parent

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In Java Spring Rest app I have following domain objects:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order")
public class Order implements Serializable {
    ....
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<PurchaseOrderItem> purchaseOrderItems = new HashSet<>();

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "total_net", precision = 10, scale = 2, nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal totalNet;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "order_item")
public class OrderItem implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Order order;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "total_net", precision = 10, scale = 2, nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal totalNet;
}
```

There is aggregate column in order entity - which should contain sum of all totalNet per orderItem and when orderItem is added or removed totalNet of order should be updated as well.

What would be best way to achieve this?

Current implementation is through services like

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class OrderItemService {

  public OrderItemDTO save(OrderItemDTO orderItemDTO) {
    orderItem orderItem = mapper.toEntity(orderItemDTO);

    orderItem = orderItemRepository.save(orderItem);

    if (orderItemDTO.getOrderId() != null) {
        OrderDTO orderResult = orderService.findOne( orderItemDTO.getOrderId()).get();
        orderService.save(orderResult);
        //total is calculated in save method of parent
    }

    return mapper.toDto(orderItem);
  }
}
```

This looks like being wrong flow ... 
Using EntityEventListeners with @PostUpdate @PostRemove would be correct here?

Comment: I would add addPurchaseOrderItem and removePurchaseOrderItem on Order. For me these methods would be needed anyway to take care of the bidirectional relathionship between order and order item. Having these methods and having all of bussiness logic using only them (instead of direct setters on order and order item) it would be no big deal (upon usage) to fire the recalculation of the totalNet as well.

Comment: PrePersist and PostLoad would help you too but they do not help in the situation when the bussiness logic changes the data in memory, i.e. the totalNet would be possibly wrong until the order is persisted. Also the magical PrePersist and PostLoad are not so helpfull in unit test scenarios (that might or might not be an issue for you).

Comment: @Michal Great discussion! thanks! unit test is a must.. what I notice already while experimenting and you also confirmed - EntityEventListeners is not the way I would go. Considering scenario of addPurchaseOrderItem and removePurchaseOrderItem - seems to be correct ...